# How to get a datetime property in orientdb3.0 in ISO 8601 format

Tags: java, date, properties, orientdb, orientdb3.0

I'm trying to get a datetime property from OrientDB in ISO 8601 format like
"2020-05-21T09:30:00.123Z"

I apply it to database as "ALTER DATABASE DATETIMEFORMAT "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'".

When i call property of vertex as "vert.getProperty("DATE")" it return me a datetime like this "Thu May 21 14:07:00 CEST 2020"

Then i parse it to format ISO 8601:

```
protected Instant parseDateTimeOdb(String fechaHora) {

    Instant result = ZonedDateTime.parse(fechaHora, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ROOT)).toOffsetDateTime().toInstant();
    WriteLog.debug("La cadena de OrientDB convertida vale: " + result);

    return result;
```

But after parse milisecond always are "000"

How can i get this property correctly?

Comment: "But after parse milisecond always are '000'" What did you expect the milliseconds to be?

Comment: In this case for example ""2020-05-21T09:30:00.123Z"" must be '123'

Comment: But in the format you got - "Thu May 21 14:07:00 CEST 2020", there are no milliseconds.

Comment: Correct, but in database it's correctly saved.  " #27:14   14   LIAudioFile   18   14   020-05-21T09:30:00.123Z  "

The question y how can i get all "datetime" correctly?